# RDP protocol for c++

Tags: c++, tcp, connection, protocols, remote-desktop

Im looking for code that connects to another computer via remote desktop connection and checks if the connection was successful or not.

I packet logged and found out there was a galaxy worth of packets so i was wondering if there was some easy code out there.

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense at all.  RDP is a protocol, a set of rules of communication between two nodes.  The handling of message control is normally handled by a protocol like TCP at level 4 of the OSI model.  RDP is an application layer protocol, it doesn't need to worry about connections etc...

Comment: Well, There's a whole big stack above TCP (atleast TPKT,X.225 and ROSE) , RDP doesn't sit directly on top of TCP. If you want to communicate using RDP, you have to implement all those layers (bar the ones your OS supports)

Answer (score 5):

There really isn't anything easy about RDP, that protocol stack is huge and builds on the ITU OSI protocols, which includes a fair amount of ASN.1/BER.

Your best bet is the code that's in [FreeRDP](http://www.freerdp.com/).

Answer (score 1):

A bit of terminology: you want a "RDP client library for C++".

As others have mentioned, look into the "FreeRDP" and "rdesktop" projects.

With FreeRDP, you're going to get a suite of libraries (each one doing it's thing).  With rdesktop, you're going to get a client app (which you have to break the C code out of, and "build" your C++ api around).

If this is a new project, I'd pick FreeRDP over rdesktop, as they have libraries available with your C++ interface already in place.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to check if an RDP server is present, but not authenticate? In this case all you'd need are the first couple of packets used to negotiate protocol security. You can find the code in FreeRDP in libfreerdp-core/nego.c.

Answer (score 0):

@Blanker1231 : You should have look on [**rdesktop code**](http://www.rdesktop.org/) , its in c but can be very easily modified to be used in a C++ code , all you have to do is bridge their Struct Stream effectively .

moreover I have worked on a Rdp 7+ implementation ages ago in qt/c++ for a  , so recently just for fun of it i used all of my experience and wrote a RDP parser and code generator and open sourced it on https://github.com/shashanksingh/Code-Generator-for-RDP
Right now it dead simple and i am still working on it more intelligent .  Word of caution it doesn't generate everything . Examples includes demo.def which on compilation will generate all the class os ms-fscc used in ms-rdp 
@Blanker1231 if you ever feel like , just fork the implementation and start pushing stuff in